# Missing decorators specifier in lit package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, lit

I have installed lit package via npm, then i replaced my-element.ts file with my own .ts file and also updated the package.json file with the new .ts file

[Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n0XK.png)

`import { LitElement,html,css } from "lit";
import { customElement, property } from "lit/decorators";

@customElement('sample_project')
export class SampleProject extends LitElement {
static styles = css`p {color:blue}`;

```
@property()
name = 'Intro';

render(){
    return html`<p>Hello, ${this.name}!</p>`;
}
```

}`

I tried running the component on local host with npm run dev, I get an error that says it's missing ./decorators specifier in 'lit' package but weird because I have installed web dev server npm to try to solve the problem.

expecting this to run and render Hello intro only, very basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the extension.

```js
import { customElement, property } from "lit/decorators.js";
```

The package exports is defined with the `.js` extension in the `package.json` https://github.com/lit/lit/blob/b0c3f82ef0f97326a205e77e7e1043b75a5cc53f/packages/lit/package.json#L28 so it must match that for the module to be resolved.

You can read more about why the `lit` package does that here: https://lit.dev/docs/tools/publishing/#include-file-extensions-in-import-specifiers

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the decorators directory cannot be found in the lit package you installed, therefore Vite complains that the path does not exist.

Double check manually if `./node_modules/lit/decorators` exists. If it does, try to provide the import using the full directory path.